# A unitary that induces Entanglement Breaking Channel for any ancillary state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Let's say there is a unitary operator $M:\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2\to\mathcal{H}_A\otimes\mathcal{H}_B$ such that the channel $\Phi$ given as
$$\Phi(\rho)=\text{Tr}_BM(\rho\otimes\phi)M^\dagger$$
is always an Entanglement-Breaking (EB) channel for any pure state $\phi$ on $\mathcal{H}_2$. Does this condition give any constraints to the structure of the unitary operator $M$?

As a question in the similar vein, let's say there is a channel given in the form
$$\Psi(\rho)=V(\rho\otimes\sigma)V^\dagger$$
for a fixed mixed state $\sigma$, and this channel $\Psi$ always outputs separable state. Does this give any nontrivial constraint to $V$ or $\sigma$?